# Replace a word in text file with another word using macro

Tags: vba, ms-word

The below code is working for me to replace a word ("This") in text file to another word ("That").Similarly i need to replace one more word with in the same text file.

my requirement is replace the word "This" to "That"
and replace "From" to "TO".Can you modify the below code accordingly.

```
 Sub  ReplaceStringInFile()

    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFil As Object
    Dim objFil2 As Object
    Dim StrFileName As String
    Dim StrFolder As String
    Dim SstrAll As String

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    StrFolder = "c:\macro\"
    StrFileName = Dir(StrFolder & "*.txt")

    Do While StrFileName <> vbNullString
        Set objFil = objFSO.opentextfile(StrFolder & StrFileName)
        strAll = objFil.readall
        objFil.Close
        Set objFil2 = objFSO.createtextfile(StrFolder & StrFileName)
        objFil2.Write Replace(strAll, "THIS", "THAT")
        objFil2.Close
        StrFileName = Dir
    Loop
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line replaces "this" with "that".

```
objFil2.Write Replace(strAll, "THIS", "THAT")
```

Just add this line under it:

```
objFil2.Write Replace(strAll, "From", "To")
```

EDIT:

Sorry, I haven't tested the code. Try this instead:

```
    Sub ReplaceStringInFile()

    Dim objFSO As Object, objFil As Object, objFil2 As Object
    Dim StrFileName As String, StrFolder As String, strAll As String, newFileText As String

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    StrFolder = "c:\macro\"
    StrFileName = Dir(StrFolder & "*.txt")

    Do While StrFileName <> vbNullString
        Set objFil = objFSO.opentextfile(StrFolder & StrFileName)
        strAll = objFil.readall
        objFil.Close
        Set objFil2 = objFSO.createtextfile(StrFolder & StrFileName)
        'change this to that in text
        newFileText = Replace(strAll, "THIS", "THAT")
        'change from to to in text
        newFileText = Replace(newFileText, "from", "to")
        'write file with new text
        objFil2.Write newFileText
        objFil2.Close
        StrFileName = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: it is not working i have tested.only the word  "from" will change to "to"  word "THIS" is not changing to "THAT"

Comment: Replace function is case sensitive by default. As niton wrote use option compare text. Your line of code should look like this "newFileText = Replace(strAll, "THIS", "THAT", 1, -1, vbTextCompare)".

Comment: not working.. only replacing one word the other one is not changing  can u help .

Comment: @user3668427 Have you used vbTextCompare in replace function?

Comment: @user3668427 I've changed one more thing in the code. It should work now. Give it a try and let me know.

Comment: In the same document i need to replace the second line with the 5 th line...Is that possible using macros can you please help

Comment: @user3668427 you could try to use split function with chr(13) as delimiter to get the content of your file into an array and then do the changes you want. After that you can use join on that array to get  it back into one string and save it to your file.

Comment: I have posted this as a seperate question.can you please see that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25381056/replace-third-line-of-each-file-inside-a-folder-with-second-line-using-macros

Answer (score 0):

Should work. Try Option Compare Text so it is not case sensitive.