# Replace Third line of each file inside a folder with second line using Macros

Tags: vba, excel

I am using the below VBA code to replace few words in all the  files inside one folder.in the same VBA code is it possible to copy the third line of each file  and replace it with the second line.

```
Sub ReplaceStringInFile1()

    Dim objFSO As Object, objFil As Object, objFil2 As Object
    Dim StrFileName As String, StrFolder As String, strAll As String, newFileText As String

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    StrFolder = "I:\Documents\ABC\AZ\"
    StrFileName = Dir(StrFolder & "*.txt")

    Do While StrFileName <> vbNullString
        Set objFil = objFSO.opentextfile(StrFolder & StrFileName)
        strAll = objFil.readall
        objFil.Close
        Set objFil2 = objFSO.createtextfile(StrFolder & StrFileName)
        'change this to that in text
        newFileText = Replace(strAll, "To:", "FROM")
        'change from to to in text
        newFileText = Replace(newFileText, "THIS", "THAT")
        'write file with new text
                'change from to to in text
        newFileText = Replace(newFileText, "IS", "WAS")
        'write file with new text
        objFil2.Write newFileText
        objFil2.Close
        StrFileName = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I will tell you logic and use the logic accordingly and come up with the code if you got any issues.

Open Each Text file `ForReading` and read each line one by one using `ReadLine` and Check for end of stream using `AtEndOfStream`. Copy each line in one string but skip the second the line. Something like this

```
Do While Obj.AtEndOfStream <> True
Str = Obj.ReadLine
if i = 2 Then 
Str = ""
Else
StrF = StrF & Vbcrlf & Str 
End If
i = i + 1

Loop
```

Now Open the Text File `ForWriting`Replace the old text in files Using `Obj.Write StrF` and Close the file. Do the loop for all files in the folder.

Hope This Helps :)

Comment: Hi.i have tried this but since i am very new to VBA, i was not able to integrate this with my code.Can you please integrate the above code with my code.